# Performing one-to-many join with address and crime data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, relates, one-to-many

Goal: I want to show the police calls coming from a parcel on ArcMap. So if you click on the parcel, it will show all the calls for the year. I want to join the address attribute from the parcel data to the police file's call address (which was created by concatenating street number and address to match the parcel layer)

Issue: many addresses have more than one call from different dates; one property even had 100 calls. The parcel layer has only one polygon for each address, so I can't show multiple records for the join.

How do I join so that all 100 calls would be joined to that parcel?

Comment: Parcel ID might be a more reliable field for the join (addresses can be written in various ways, with various punctuation, abbreviation and capitalization.)

Comment: CSK - the addresses match, but I just want to have a join showing all the calls for the parcel, not just the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a join you can try to relate the police calls to the parcel layer. Right click the layer in arcmap and go to joins and relates.  Choose relate and set up the relationship.

[image]

Once the relate is set open the attribute table and click on the first icon in the table toolbar and navigate to the related tables choice.  This should show you the calls that are located at each parcel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a WKT geometry column in the Parcels layer. Then join parcels to Calls table via table or location join. Include any desired fields in the join along with the WKT geometry field. You can then produce a new layer with a parcel shape derived from the WKT field that will have a parcel polygon per call.

Alternatively you can store the relation data in a separate table for analysis by address or parcel ID. Join the parcel ID or address to the calls field, if it is not already there. Then run any analysis you desire, group by parcel ID or address. The analysis could then be joined back to the parcel shape layer for display.

As CSK said, Parcel ID would be best for this since addresses are often not unique.